# Retrofit error URL path must start with '/'

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm getting strange error using Retrofit. After sending request to one of the endpoints I'm receiving error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RodoService.getRodoInfo: URL path "xxx.com" must start with '/'.
```

It's strange cause other endpoints work. It's working also using postman so backend seems to be ok.

Here's my interface :

```
public interface RodoService {


    String INFO_RODO = BASE_API_URL + "rodo/players/";

    @GET(INFO_RODO)
    void getRodoInfo(Callback<BaseResponse<RodoModel>> callback);

}
```

My second class :

```
public class RodoApi extends BaseApi {

    private final RodoService service = restAdapter.create(RodoService.class);

    public RodoApi() {
        super();
    }

    public void getRodo(Callback<BaseResponse<RodoModel>> callback) {
        service.getRodoInfo(callback);
    }
}
```

And in Activity I'm calling API like this :

```
RodoApi rodoApi = new RodoApi();
        rodoApi.getRodo(new Callback<BaseResponse<RodoModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(BaseResponse<RodoModel> rodoModelBaseResponse, Response response) {
                Log.e("RESP", "success: " + response.getBody() );
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e("RESP", "error: " + error.getMessage() );


            }
        });
```

Can you help me please ? As I said - other endponts work. Thanks!

Comment: well what is your `BASE_API_URL`

Comment: It's correct. Lets say : "http://google.com"

Comment: Have you tried to put it like that  "/rodo/players/" ?

Comment: Yes , I did. URL is correct :/

Comment: add / to the end of your base URL

Comment: I tried, not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code. You concatenate BASE_URL + End Point and passed it to @GET annotation

Look @ Interface I wrote

```
public interface RequestInterface {

  @GET("recent")
  Observable<MovieResponse> getRecentMovies(); 
}
```

BASE URL Implementation in RequestService Class

```
public class RequestService {


   private static final String TAG = RequestService.class.getSimpleName();

   public static final String BASEURL = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/filmystanapi/public/api/v1/";



   private RequestInterface requestInterface;

   public RequestService() {
       initRequestInterface();
   }


   private void initRequestInterface() {

       requestInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASEURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(RequestInterface.class);
    }


    public Observable<MovieResponse> getRecentMovies() {

         return requestInterface.getRecentMovies()
                .retry(5)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .filter(movieResponse -> movieResponse.getStatus() == 200);
    }
}
```

This may be issue with your error code.

Comment: I dont know if it suits my issue ... I think it's very similar solution as mine

Comment: try it once and let me know